# Add class to parent and children if class exist and match location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Vertical Toggle Menu with Submenus and trying to add them classes if I match the location. Before the classes are added it should check if there are a classes "active" on the parents.

It does not matter how deep it is going, it should add to any parent (li.active) the class "open" and to children (ul.nav) "display:block" if is matching the location to keep the menu open.

```
nav.main-cat
> li.active
>> a.nav-sub
>> ul.nav
>>> li.active
>>>> a.nav-sub
```

The Code

```
$('.main-cat a').filter(function () {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().find('.active').addClass('open').children().next('.nav').css('display','block');
```

My Problem is that it only add to the deepest Menu the classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it should add to any parent (li.active)

I guess this bit `.parent().find('.active')` can be replaced with `.parent('.active')`

If you want all parents of selected `a`, then you need to call `.parents('.active')`

Finally, this bit `.css('display','block')`  should definitely go into CSS.

Post a fiddle so we can look more precisely.

Comment: It did! Thanks a lot!